# Finding Angle in SSS Triangle JAVA

Tags: java, angle

I need help calculating the angle between the 5 and the 3. I have absolutely no idea how to even model the question, let alone convert it to java. This is entirely specific, does not need to be abstracted.

```
int a=3; int b=4; int c=5;
```

is honestly as far as I can get. This would be cos(b), right? I just need a quick pointer/solution

Comment: I think the implementation would be quite straight forward if you understood the math so the starting point could be http://math.stackexchange.com/ not stackoverflow or http://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this a right-triangle?  So the 5 is the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle)?

If that's the case, you need to find any one of the following (which should all be equal to each other): arctan(4/3), ArcSin(4/5), or arccos(3/5).

For example, using the first:

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(4.0/3.0))
```